# in python how to give each letter in a string of characters a individual numeric value and store the results independently?

Tags: python, string, encryption

Trying to create an algorithm that takes in a password as a key. I am trying to assign each letter of the alphabet a numeric value so I can use the values to decipher the encryption. I have found ways of assigning a letter a value but can't figure out how to use each letter in the password as a individual value?

Comment: Do you have any code right now?

Comment: There is a natural mapping of characters in a string to their indices.

Comment: Have just started to look into the problem so no code as of yet just seeing if anyone one knows of any tips and tricks on how best to store the individual values. I have a idea of how to take in a single character and give it  a value but when in a string i am unsure as it might just take in just one value or a combination of them all?

Answer (score 0):

Using the unicode values of the characters as a value `ord()`:

```
>>> password = "my password"
>>> for char in password:
...  print ord(char)
... 
109
121
32
112
97
115
115
119
111
114
100
```

Comment: Yeah i have something similar in how have been looking to do it but the problem in i need to refer to specific entries. been thinking of using some sort of array and then being able to refer to the value of the 2nd letter of the password and subtract it from the last digit if that makes sense? its the storing and referring to them is where my mind goes blank.